# Centered form, after button

Tags: html, css

I intend to have a long input form centered. AFTER THAT I need to place a submit button 15px after the form's right end. Could you please help me to code it? Thank you.

Note: I want to have only the form centered and after that add a button.

My attempt:

```html
<div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; ">
  <form action="file.php">
    <center><input type="text"  name="c2" style="width: 79%; font-size:25pt;"></center>
    <input type="submit" value="send" style="position: relative; left: 15px">
  </form>
</div>
```

Adding a photo:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Don't use `<center>`. It's [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Instead use CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox would be one of several possibilities.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inp {
  width: 79%; 
  font-size:25pt;  
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; ">
  <form action="file.php">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="c2" class="inp">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="send" style="position: relative; left: 15px">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATED (again)**

```css
.main { display: flex; }
.a, .b, .c { background: red;  }
.b { flex: 1; text-align: center; }
.c {margin-left: auto;}

.inp {
  width: 79%; 
  font-size:25pt;  
}

.sub {
  position: relative; 
  right: 15px; 
  top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b">
        <form action="file.php">
          <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="c2" class="inp">
          </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <input type="submit" value="send" class="sub">      
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE (2)**

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inp {
  width: 79%; 
  font-size:25pt;  
  position: relative; left: 15px
}

.sub {
  position: relative; left: 30px
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; ">
  <form action="file.php">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="c2" class="inp">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="send" class="sub">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for you reply. I intend to have centered the input form only. After that I want to add a button. I do not want the form and the button centered both together.

Comment: @Jan I updated my answear. i put the submit field outside the wraper div. but inner the form.

Comment: But now the button is on the next line instead on the same as the form..

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only the form centered. And the button on the right of it. Can you please help?

Comment: @Jan I updated again ;-) like that?

Comment: Thank you Maik. I also think that a div on the left is a solution, however in the last code is the form kind of not centered..

Comment: @Jan it only looks like that. if you press the full-page button, you will see that it is centred. To do what you want in the flexbox system you need three divs. left (empty), middle (form), right, button. you can then position this with top, right etc..

Comment: Thank you Maik. Please see the initial post. There is an image explaining the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: @Jan Ok. I have implemented it with a little trick like this. I took variant one. then assigned the input field position:relative and then gave left:15px;. I then assigned the button left:30px;. `Upate (2)`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much Maik for your patience and help.

Comment: @Jan You welcome! if it was helpful it would be nice if you acept my answear ;)

Comment: I did. I choose yours as the best one and I also voted up. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using flexbox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

```css
.form-container {
    background-color: red; 
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="file.php">
    <div class="form-container">
        <input type="text"  name="c2" style="width: 79%; font-size:25pt;">
        <input type="submit" value="send" style="position: relative; left: 15px">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello Conrado. Your solution is nice, thank you. However it is longer than the screen.. on the right.

Comment: Ah, ok, missed a 0 on padding. Fixed.